# How often do downvoters come back and explain?

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes

When you downvote a post, it's considered polite to leave a comment explaining why, but it's not required.

We often see comments from the original poster asking why a post was downvoted. (I've done it myself.) Often the response to such a comment is either silence, or "I didn't downvote, but ...".

How often do downvoters actually come back and explain their downvotes? I'm asking only about downvoters who don't initially leave comments. (If the answer is "never", it implies that comments asking for explanations of downvotes are useless, or nearly so.)

It may not be possible to answer this definitively.

(Part of my motivation for asking this question, assuming the answer is "seldom or never", was to have a place to point when responding to "Why the downvote?" comments. It took me a while to learn that complaining about downvotes isn't particularly useful.)

Comment: Of course this can't be answered without having vote data. Why would you want to know this?

Comment: *"it implies that comments asking for explanations of downvotes are useless"* .. well, they largely are and to some extent are noise. I can understand that some OP's are truly interested, but in my experience, more often than not it's not an attempt to start a constructive discussion.

Comment: @slhck: Two reasons: Sheer idle curiosity, and wondering whether there's any point to the "downvoter please explain" comments. I doubt that a definitive answer is possible, but there might be anecdotal evidence of comments like "I downvoted because ...".

Comment: Probably almost never, because once users downvote and move on, they typically don't look at the post again. But asking why something was downvoted can be beneficial, as other users who see the post may be able to identify why it was downvoted, and can supply a possible reason so you know what not to do next time.

Comment: Answer downvotes are sometimes just like a genie that suddenly appears and farts in your face before disappearing into thin air; and you know that they will be back, you just don't know when.

Comment: @Jack - so *that's* who that guy was...

Comment: Not an answer, but I used to explain downvotes, but when the revenge votes started to pile up I just thought meh...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables It's the only explanation :)

Comment: Peraonal practice != answer: I often comment (on sites that don't discourage it), but if I didn't comment or up-vote an existing comment on the first pass, I'm unlikely to comment later.  I do look at the post again if it crosses my path, in case the author fixed the problem and I should remove my downvote.

Comment: I downvote randomly, and never leave a comment. If the person asks for a reason in the comments, I never explain myself, I just laugh and laugh and laugh and laugh until tears leak from my eyes and my bladder slips a little. The feeling of power and vengeance I get from reckless downvoting makes me drunk with pleasure. My friends staged an intervention, but I downvoted them and left them sitting in my living room tearing at their hair and wondering why. I downvote because it makes me feel alive. You'll never take it from me. Never.

Comment: @PeeHaa Are revenge votes really that common? I hand hand out quite a few downvotes, and rarely get them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't have access to the downvote data, but we do have access to the comment data.

Here's [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/99294) that

- looks for a comment that has `*Why*Downvote*` or `*downvoter care*`
- followed by a comment that has `*I was *downvote*` or `*I downvote*` or `*I am *downvote*` or `-1 This is wrong*`

There are currently 236 results. While it's not a precise picture, I suspect it's none the less an accurate one. People generally don't answer.

Comment: This doesn't account for 'I (was|am) the downvoter' or 'Downvoted because' or 'Downvoter care to comment?' or '-1 This is wrong' or any other variation of phrasing. Just sayin'.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I updated the query to include your variations. It went to 236. Still not a whole lot

Comment: Why downvotez me! (couldn't resist)

Comment: I can haz eksplanshun 4 why u dwnvtn?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter the sheer volume of ways your query can miss makes it completely useless

Comment: Also, though; other language could have been used in the reply, like a simple explanation without preamble. Or, someone who didn't down vote could have replied, without stating they *didn't*. There's no way to connect who actually down voted with who commented.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar No, but here's a cheezburger.

Comment: Erh ma gerd! Cherzbergerz! Mah fervert! .......Okay, I'll stop now.

Comment: @SamIam the sheer volume of the ways your comment doesn't contribute anything makes it useless

Comment: Aww, man; I always miss the good (bad) stuff! Hmm... actually no; that's not true. Not true at all. Not one bit. Nope. Not true... (Actually, now that I've posted this, turns out it's *not* true!)

Comment: A more concrete answer than I was expecting. Thanks.

Comment: Might want to change that query to remove the trailing "e" from "downvote" as it won't catch the likely candidate "downvoting".

Comment: Sometimes, the explanation comes very fast after the downvote happens (I usually do that), in which case you don't get anything from the query.