# Why are comments silently deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

[I posted what I think was a very legit question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78172910/how-do-i-implement-anti-forgery-in-blazor-ver-8-interactiveserver). Within 5 minutes it had 2 down votes. So I posted a comment asking why the down votes? I never got a reply (and one of the down votes went away).

But here's the weird thing - today my comment is gone. There's no record of it. I was not aware that could even happen.

Who can do that? When are they supposed to? And is asking why the down votes not allowed? Because without an explanation, how can I learn why what I think is a very appropiate question for this site down voted?

Comment: asking "why the downvotes" is not constructive. If you want to be constructive you could ask how you could improve your post, after all isn't that what you really want to know?

Comment: Comments are third-rate, they are supposed to be temporary and will be removed if not constructive.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think both ways of phrasing it are asking the same thing - but I'll use your suggested wording in the future.

Comment: "and one of the down votes went away" No, it didn't. Your question still has 2 downvotes, but someone else subsequently upvoted, which changed the overall score from -2 to -1.

Comment: [Because it's not productive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/165455), (also see the 250+ questions linked to and/or closed as a duplicate of that one), and because moderators are free to delete comments which are noisy, chatty, or can't possibly lead anywhere good. I'm not suggesting the current system is perfect, but I also don't believe a perfect system is possible. If someone has constructive things to say about your post, whether they vote or not, they'll volunteer them. Badgering/forcing them, in almost all cases that I have seen and/or can imagine, just isn't going to help you.

Comment: Also see: "[Is it now discouraged to ask for reasons for downvotes as a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74559/271271)", which says comments asking for downvotes to be explained "are noise *at best*", and "[How often do downvoters come back and explain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168633/271271)"

Comment: *Ephemeral* is a great word to describe comments

Comment: Comments asking how posts can be improved are also noise.

Comment: I've always asked people for feedback on anything I do professionally. It's one of the best ways to improve. However, if it's against SO policy, then that's the system. In my opinion it's a rule that gets in the way of writing better questions.

Comment: As I said, it's an imperfect system, but from experience I know (a) not everyone tries to be constructive (and many try, but fail), and (b) no matter how constructive the rest _try_ to be, and even achieve, it's often perceived to be in the large range of _not_ constructive. Serial voting, for example, doesn't happen often because someone doesn't like your profile picture - I bet it's commonly because the person felt slighted in a comment. We can't all agree that one extreme is better/worse than the other, and I didn't always feel this way, but explaining down-votes is the worse of evils IMHO.

Comment: It's not _against_ any policy to ask for feedback; like a lot of things, it's quite subjective. But as others mentioned, saying "help me improve my post" is much less likely to get flagged than "what's with the down-votes?" This is even more true here than on main sites, since down-voting here often means something completely different (it's overloaded - sometimes it's about quality/research, but it doesn't have to be - sometimes it's just disagreement with a perfectly well-researched opinion or request).

Comment: "I think both ways of phrasing it are asking the same thing" - not at all. One of them is focused on your personal grievance; the other is focused on your apparent willingness to work within the system.

Comment: That is the nature of the SO... google for that, you are absolutely not alone